# Slow SQL Update using sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi all … Wonder if anyone out there can help me with this one please.

I am running a query to update product categories against sales lines and need to back file a few million records so I wrote the query below to run for a specific order ID

```
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = 659483

UPDATE [TradeSpace].[TradeSpace].[dbo].[SalesLine] 
   SET [ProductCategory] = [curSync].[pc_Cat] 
  FROM (SELECT [SC_ID], 
               [pc_cat] 
          FROM [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWSLines] 
         INNER 
          JOIN [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWProductCats] 
            ON [MWSLines].[pc_catref] = [MWProductCats].[pc_catref]
         WHERE [sh_id] = @ID
       ) AS [curSync]
 WHERE [SalesLine].[slID] =  [curSync].[sc_id] 
   AND [salesline].[soid] = @ID
```

The sub SELECT runs in less than one second but the update has yet to finished (have left it for an hour at most). Indexes exist for [slID] and [soid] .. a manual update for one line takes less than one seconds but run like this (10 lines) is desperately slow.

Does anybody have any clues please. I've written plenty of queries like this and never had a problem … stumped :(

Comment: Hi @David - these kinds of questions often require some additional clues. Please post table defs including PKs, indexes and constraints. Also please include the query plan output.

Comment: Hi .. I'm afraid I cannot due to the contract I have signed for the client. Can't get a query plan as it's never finished running. Running just an update with hard coded values is instant and so is the query so at a loss as to why running like this has issues. Very strange.

Comment: Ideally both pc_catref columns should be the first column in their respective indexes.

Comment: This part of the query runs fine separately and does indeed have relevant indexes. (SELECT [SC_ID], [pc_cat] FROM [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWSLines] 
    INNER JOIN [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWProductCats] ON [MWSLines].[pc_catref] = [MWProductCats].[pc_catref]
    WHERE [sh_id] = @ID) AS [curSync]    …..    I believe it's the UPDATE causing the problem ?

Comment: Is it possible that you have run into some type of locking issue?  Depending on your settings, the update may require the entire SalesLine table to be locked during the update.

Comment: If you can't wait for the actual execution plan to generate, what is the estimated execution plan?

Comment: Can you share the differences between the select showplan and the update/select showplan?

Comment: Sorry … this is my first post .. how do I add an attachment ? Thanks

Comment: You can't add attachments yourself until you get a higher rep.   The only thing you can do right now is upload an image to imgur.com and then add a link to it in your question.

Comment: Or upload the plan here. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Are there deadlocks? (Run sp_who2) 

If there are no deadlocks, how about inserting the results of your subquery into a temp table and using that temp table in your update query (join from SalesLine table to your temp table) ...

A plan definitely helps!

Comment: ok atleast you can share other detail like inner sub query return how many rows ? how many rows have [TradeSpace].[TradeSpace].[dbo].[SalesLine] 
 in all and how many rows are actually updated in the given query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query rewritten with no changes:

```
UPDATE s SET 
    ProductCategory = curSync.pc_Cat
FROM TradeSpace.TradeSpace.dbo.SalesLine s
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT [SC_ID], [pc_cat] 
    FROM [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWSLines]  l
    INNER JOIN [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWProductCats] c ON l.[pc_catref] = c.[pc_catref]
    WHERE [sh_id] = @ID
  ) AS [curSync]
  on s.[slID] =  [curSync].[sc_id]
WHERE s.[soid] = @ID
```

Are your sure everything is correct here? That single row from `SalesLine` always matches only one row from subquery?

Try this then. Will fail if this is not true. Original query would silently update same row with different values in same situation.

```
UPDATE s SET 
    ProductCategory = (
            SELECT [pc_cat] 
            FROM [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWSLines]  l
            INNER JOIN [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWProductCats] c ON l.[pc_catref] = c.[pc_catref]
            WHERE [sh_id] = @ID
              AND [sc_id] = s.[slID]
          )
FROM TradeSpace.TradeSpace.dbo.SalesLine s
WHERE s.[soid] = @ID
```

And please check  estimated execution plan. Does it hit indexes?

Answer (score 0):

We need other detail like a I mention in comments.

Your update is slow because of very high cardinality estimate when update table is join with Sub query result.

It may be because of wrong join and where predicate.

you can put the sub query result in #Temp table and try.Also you can create same index in #temp table.

```
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = 659483

create #temp table([SC_ID] int,[pc_cat] int)

insert into #temp 
SELECT [SC_ID], 
               [pc_cat] 
          FROM [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWSLines] 
         INNER JOIN [MW_MereSys].[dbo].[MWProductCats] 
            ON [MWSLines].[pc_catref] = [MWProductCats].[pc_catref]
         WHERE [sh_id] = @ID




UPDATE SalesLine 
   SET [ProductCategory] = [curSync].[pc_Cat] 
  FROM [TradeSpace].[TradeSpace].[dbo].[SalesLine] as SalesLine
inner join #temp  AS [curSync]
 WHERE [SalesLine].[slID] =  [curSync].[sc_id] 
   AND [salesline].[soid] = @ID 

drop table #temp
```